# can't add System.Drawing.dll reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, system.drawing

Ok, so I'm on this bug for the last 4 hours and I dont know what to do..

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 and I opened Consol App(.net core) project. also I'm working on windows 8.1 OS.

I wanted to use Image from the System.Drawing namespace and it keeps giving me that error:
"the type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I downloaded the System.Drawing.dll from https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_drawing_dll.html
(to the desktop) and then right click on the right project->add->Reference..->Browse..->System.Drawing.dll->OK
then I saw in the project (in the Solution Explorer) in the project dependencies->Assemblies->System.Drawing so I guess it works right?!

I'm still getting the same error and can't use the System.Drawing namespace, any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Drawing;
namespace client2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            //read image
            Image image = new Image("C:\\image\\amir.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.0-preview2-26406-04

Comment: .Net Core doesn't have that stuff by default, no...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is not part of the cross-platform parts of .NET (Core). It depends on GDI+ which is part of Windows. There are plenty of alternatives out there.

*Aside*: Never download DLLs from an untrusted source.

Comment: There is a library called [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) that is taking care of a lot of the System.Drawing namespace features. Maybe OP could utilize something in there. Also to OP, use nuget. Don’t randomly import dlls

Comment: @maccettura true. Hard to know what the op wants to do

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!
Basically I'm trying to load a bitmap image in the server and send it to the client, I allready wrote the server-client program and it works fine.